# How to keep a total between AngularJS Components in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

Here's the problem - a limited number of licences can be assigned to users, when the available number is 0 no more can be assigned and other buttons will be disabled. Licences can removed and reassigned.

The list of users is in an ngRepeat loop, and the assign / remove licence function is in a component. When I click the assign / remove button it updates itself and the total, but the button in other components don't update until the next click.

Here's the full code of what I have so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/T4soR8qpSAzY0cANknsE?p=preview

The HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="RootController as root">
    <pre>qty: {{ root.qtyAvailable }} / {{ root.qtyMax }}</pre>
    <div ng-repeat="user in root.users | orderBy: 'firstname' ">
      {{ user.firstname }}
      <assign 
        has-licence="user.hasLicence" 
        reassignable="user.reassignable"
        qty="root.qtyAvailable"
        qty-max="root.qtyMax"
      ></assign>
    </div>
</body>
```

The controller and component:

```
.controller('RootController', function() {
  this.qtyMax = 2;
  this.qtyAvailable = 1;

  this.users = [
    {firstname: 'john', hasLicence: false, reassignable: true},
    {firstname: 'jane', hasLicence: false, reassignable: true},
    {firstname: 'joey', hasLicence: false, reassignable: true},
    {firstname: 'bob', hasLicence: true, reassignable: true},
  ];

})

.component('assign', {
  template: `<button ng-click="$ctrl.click($ctrl.hasLicence)">{{ $ctrl.text }}</button>`,
  controller: function() {
    this.text = '';

    // set the button text
    this.buttonText = function() {
      if(this.hasLicence) {
        this.text = 'remove';
      }
      else if(!this.hasLicence && this.reassignable && this.qty>0) {
        this.text = 'assign';
      }
      else {
        this.text = '-'; // eg button disabled
      }
    }

    this.buttonText();

    // click function
    this.click = function(licence) {
      if(licence === true) {
        this.hasLicence = false;
        this.qty++
      }
      else if(this.qty>0) {
        this.hasLicence = true;
        this.qty--
      }
      this.buttonText(this.hasLicence);
      console.log(this.qty)
    }

  },
  bindings: {
    hasLicence: '<',
    reassignable: '<', // not relevant for this demo
    qty: '=',
    qtyMax: '<'
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  template: `<button ng-disabled="$ctrl.qty <= 0 && !$ctrl.hasLicence" ng-click="$ctrl.click($ctrl.hasLicence)">{{ $ctrl.text }}</button><span ng-if="$ctrl.qty <= 0 && !$ctrl.hasLicence">No licenses are free</span>`
```

Using extendend syntax : `ng-disabled="$ctrl.qty <= 0 && !$ctrl.hasLicence"` for only disabling the buttons to add a license when the 'free licenses' var is <= 0.

Updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aESgZxM1VzP0a17LWk1Z?p=preview)

Comment: awesome, thanks. this is exactly what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the `buttonText()` function specifically you can add a watch on the `qty` variable and execute it:

```
.component('assign', {
  template: `<button ng-click="$ctrl.click($ctrl.hasLicence)">{{ $ctrl.text }}</button>`,
  controller: function($scope) { // $scope injection here

    ...

    // Note: you can use arrow functions to omit the assignment of context
    var me = this;
    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return me.qty;
    }, function() {
      me.buttonText();
    });

  },
  bindings: {
    ...
  }

});
```

Updated plunker here: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IqOO92A8q8EkppOUGAeG?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks very much! I wanted to avoid injecting $scope (should have put that in my question)